# DISCORD.PY Interaction ui view error in a cog

Tags: python, discord.py

i need one command for unmarry, see the SQLITE and delete two lines, but my iteraction with buttons don't work in a cog see my code, idk how discord.ui.view work for fix this, coz when i pass the author.id this return's me the message <discord.ext.commands.context.Context object at 0x000001EC42A231D0>

```
`import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from utils.embeds import *
import sqlite3
from discord.ui import Button, View
from database.init_db import connect_db
import datetime

class marryCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.embeds_cogs = embedsCog(client)
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("./database/falsosdb.db")  # Substitua "database.db" pelo nome do seu arquivo de banco de dados
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()


    @commands.command()
    async def divorce(self, ctx, conjuge: discord.Member = None):
        author_id = ctx.author.id

        if conjuge is None:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Divorce Confirmation", description=f"Você tem certeza que deseja se divorciar? {author_id}")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Divorce Confirmation", description=f"Você tem certeza que deseja se divorciar de {conjuge.mention}?")

        message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=DivorceView(ctx, author_id, conjuge))

        await ctx.message.delete()

        self.conn.close()        

class DivorceView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author_id: discord.Member, conn, cursor):
        super().__init__()
        self.author_id = author_id
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("./database/falsosdb.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="Confirmar", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def confirm_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        self.divorce_query(self.author_id)
        await interaction.response.send_message("Você se divorciou", ephemeral=True)
        self.stop()
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="Cancelar", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def cancel_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"{interaction.user.id}, ID DE QUEM INTERAGIU {self.author_id}")

        #async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        #    return interaction.user.id == self.author.id
            
    def divorce_query(self, id):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM marry WHERE id_casado = ? OR id_conjuge = ?", (id, id))
        rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM marry WHERE id_casado = ? OR id_conjuge = ?", (row[0], row[2]))
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(marryCog(client))`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=DivorceView(ctx, author_id, conjuge))
```

Here, you are parsing `ctx` as an argument, and in your view class

```
class DivorceView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author_id: discord.Member, conn, cursor):
        super().__init__()
        self.author_id = author_id
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("./database/falsosdb.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
```

This only takes `author_id`, `conn` and `cursor`.

`conn` and `cursor` are also defined in `__init__` so are not needed as an argument.

`author_id` is not an appropriate name for the variable if you are setting it to `discord.Member`.

```
...
message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=DivorceView(author_id))
...


class DivorceView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author_id: discord.Member):
        super().__init__()
        self.author_id = author_id
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("./database/falsosdb.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
```

What confuses me is how you are annotating `conjuge` as `discord.Member` in your command. So whether you're parsing the author id (int) or the `discord.Member` object, is all on you.

Comment: omg, its right, im thinking i need a pass all this arguments, but no, Thank you so much for explain this